# How to find the inverse of F(x), where F is a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse

I have a cumulative distribution function $F(x)= \mathbb P(X < x)$.

Now, for some further purposes, I need to find its inverse. The case is also that I am dealing with a KS test, where I have the implication: $\sup |F_n(X) - F(X)|$. So, what does it mean if I define the inverse of $F$ as

$$
F^{-1}(y)= \min \{F(x)>y\} \>?
$$

What does this represent visually? And why is it $F(x)>y$ that we are looking at? (I can see how it comes about algebraically, but I cannot visualise it).

Comment: The cumulative distribution function is usually defined as  $F(x)=\Pr(X \le x)$, i.e. is right continuous.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/quantile-function-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a visualisation try this with the CDF and its reflection

[image]

and note the vertical green line segments which strictly are not parts of the functions but appear as horizontal line segments in the reflections.