# Inequalities of the quantile function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory

I'm trying to rigorously prove the following inequalities involving the quantile function $Y(a) = \inf \{x \in\mathbb{R} : a \leq F(x)\}$ where $F$ is the distribution function:

1) $F(x) < a \iff x < Y(a)$

2) $a \leq F(x) \iff  Y(a) \leq  x$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quantile function properties](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/quantile-function-properties)

Comment: Your definition of the quantile function is not right. There is no lower limit on $x$ so the infimum is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As pointed by @cardinal related answers are available at [Quantile function properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/quantile-function-properties).**

For any $p\in (0,1)$ and $F$ cumulative distribution function of a given random variable, let us define the **quantile function** $Q$:
$$Q(p) \triangleq \inf \{x\in \mathbb{R} : p\leq F(x) \}$$
This is also called the **generalized inverse distribution function**, and it is denoted by $F^{-1}$. Note first that $F$ is monotone increasing and does not, in general, have an inverse (hence the *generalized* terminology above).

Note also that $Q$ is monotone increasing too (based on the fact that, if $A\subseteq B$ and $\inf A$, $\inf B$ exist, then $\inf A \geq \inf B$).

Moreover, $Q(F(x))\leq x$ for all $x$ and $F(Q(p))\geq p$ for all $p$, simply by the definition of $\inf$ and $Q$ itself.

Using these statements, we get that **$Q(p)\leq x$ if and only if $p\leq F(x)$**.

Hope it helps. (Please don't use $\omega$ as a variable of the cdf or quantile function. It's usually reserved for elements in the sample space $\Omega$ on which the random variable is defined, hidden here.)