# Prove that $F(F^{-1}(x)) \leq x$, where equality fails iff $x$ is in the interior or at the right end of a flat piece of $F$ for generalized inverse.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, continuity

I want to prove that that $F(F^{-1}(x)) \leq x$, where equality fails iff $x$ is in the interior or at the right end of a flat piece of $F$. $F$  is a non-decreasing, right continuous, $[0,1]$-valued function over $\mathbb{R}$, and the quantile function is defined as

$$
F^{-1} (p) = \inf\{ x : F(x) \geq p \}.
$$

The proof for the first part of the statement, $F(F^{-1}(x)) \leq x$, seems rather straight forward and can be found for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/quantile-function-properties).
However, I struggle with understanding and proving the second part.

I understand flat pieces of $F$ to correspond to jumps in $F^{-1}$, as depicted in the image below, taken from [these](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eembrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf) notes on generalized inverses and quantile functions.

[image: Generalized-inverse]

However, from this I'm not able to understand why the second property holds and how interiors come into play.

Any help with proving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not understanding because the properties are wrong. $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are switched it should be $F^{-1}(F(x)) \leq x$ not $F(F^{-1}(x)) \leq x$

Comment: The statement is false, it should be $F(F^{-1}(x))\geq x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Consider what happens when $I=(a, b)$ and  $F(x)=F(a)=F(a+)$ for all $a<x<b$, and $F(b-)<F(b)$. What is $Q(b)$? and what is $Q(x)$ for all $a\leq x<b$?

Comment: Yes, I typed this wrong when I made the post. Like @0XLR says, it should be $F^{-1}(F(x)) \leq x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are switched. The result should read

> If $F: \mathbb R \to [0, 1]$ is non-decreasing, right continuous, then $F^{-1}(F(x)) \leq x$ with equality failing iff $x$ is in the interior or at the right end of a flat piece of $F$.

To show that last parts first suppose $x$ is "in the interior of a flat piece of $F$". Rigorously, there are $x_1 < x < x_2$ s.t. $F := p$ flatly on $[x_1, x_2]$. So $F(x) = p = F(x_1)$ but $x_1 < x$. Hence
$x_1$ is in the set $\{s \in \mathbb R : p \leq F(s)\}$ and so $F^{-1}(F(x)) = \inf\{s \in \mathbb R : p \leq F(s)\} \leq x_1 < x$. A similar analysis goes for $x$ "at the right end of a flat piece of $F$".

Conversely suppose $x_1 = F^{-1}(F(x)) < x$ and let $p = F(x)$. By right continuity of $F$ the infimum $x_1$ of the set $\{s \in \mathbb R : p \leq F(s)\}$ is achieved within it i.e. $p \leq F(x_1)$. So as each $x_1 \leq s \leq x$ satisfies $F(x_1) \leq F(s) \leq F(x) = p$ (since $F$ is non-decreasing), this implies $F(s) = p$ for all $s \in [x_1, x]$. That is, $F$ is at least flat on $[x_1, x]$ (and possibly on a larger region). So $x$ is either on the interior or at the right end of a flat piece of $F$.